# Microsoft Report Textbox to Form Textbox

Tags: vb.net, report, reporting

My Microsoft Report Computes the totals in the Table and the total value I want to Get the value of the Total in Microsoft Report to The textbox in my form

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Don't try to extract data from a report like that.  Simply query the database to get the data you need and perform the appropriate calculations on it, the same way the report does.

Comment: Thanks I just do the calculation to the datagridview table

Comment: and set parameters to the report